# How can I add a styling only to the icons without the links?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am building the React/Redux application, and I was wondering if it's possible to apply styling only to icons without links.  I use fontawesome icons in a form of  tag, and wrap it with  tag.  I want to make the icons into grey only when there is no value in the href attribute of the parent  tags.

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href={test.officialLinks.Reddit} target="_blank">
        <i className="fab fa-reddit-alien"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href={test.officialLinks.Website} target="_blank">
        <i className="fas fa-globe"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an empty attribute selector for the `a` tag in a combined selector as follows (I made it red to make it more obvious):

```css
a > i {
color: green;
}
a[href=""] > i {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
        <i className="fab fa-reddit-alien">icon_placeholder</i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <i className="fas fa-globe">icon_placeholder</i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, if your `<i>` tags without links would not be surrounded by an `<a>` tag. This could be done using the Child Combinator selector `>`

```css
    i {
      display:block
    }
    
    ul > li > a > i {
      background:red
    }
    
    ul > li > i {
      background:grey
    }
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li>
        <i class="fab fa-reddit-alien">ss</i>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href={contract.officialLinks.Telegram} target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane">ss</i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href={contract.officialLinks.Website} target="_blank">
        <i class="fas fa-globe">ss</i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```